# Does source binding require a single root element even for non-arrays?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

The [documentation on source binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/source) has an aside which states:

> Important: A single root element should be used in the template when
>   binding to an array. Having two first level DOM elements will result
>   in an erratic behavior.

However, I'm finding that this is the case even for non arrays.

I have the following HTML, which sets up two div's populated by two templates. The only difference is that the working template wraps that databound spans in a div.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script id="broken-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      Foo: <span data-bind="text: foo"></span><br/>
      Foo Again: <span data-bind="text: foo"></span>
  </script>
  <script id="working-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <div>
            Foo: <span data-bind="text: foo"></span><br/>
            Foo Again: <span data-bind="text: foo"></span>
      </div>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="broken-div" data-template="broken-template" data-bind="source: this">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="working-div" data-template="working-template" data-bind="source: this">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript simply creates a view model with a single property and binds it to both divs:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({foo: "bar"});

kendo.bind($("#broken-div"), viewModel);
kendo.bind($("#working-div"), viewModel);
```

In both cases, only the first root element and it's children are being bound properly. This suggests that every time I databind to template with more than one element I need to make sure it is wrapped in a single root.

Is this behavior documented somewhere? Is there a bug in Kendo or in my sample code? An explanation for why Kendo requires a single root would be great to hear as well.

([Sample code as a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/649B9/1/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented except in the one place you mentioned. Such is the state of Kendo UI documentation - it's less than complete. I've been using Kendo UI for three years and as far as I can tell you, this is its default behavior and not a bug. Unfortunately, it's one of the many quirks you simply learn (stumble upon) from experience.